# How parse JSON into Postman Flow?

Tags: json, postman, jsonpath

I have next JSON:

```
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "models",
  "name": "model_auto",
  "paths": {
    "/api/v1/vehicleModels": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Возвращает список автопроизводителей",
        "description": "Возвращает список автопроизводителей",
        "operationId": "1"
      }
    },
    "/api/v1/vehicleModels/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Поиск списка по его id",
        "description": "Поиск списка по его id",
        "operationId": "2"
      }
    },
    "/api/v1/vehicleCategorys": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Список 3",
        "description": "Возвращает список 3",
        "operationId": "3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get only keys into paths object. If i use JSON Path i quickly find keys:
`$.paths.*~`:

```
[
  "/api/v1/vehicleModels",
  "/api/v1/vehicleModels/{id}",
  "/api/v1/vehicleCategorys"
]
```

But i use Postman Flow and want get these values into it. How can I get only keys into Postman Flow application?

I try some Postman Flow tools: Evaluate, Select and now i didn't find any working solution.
If I use script:

```
for (var key=0 in jsonData.paths) {
            console.log(key)
        }
```

But i need to get this into Flow

Comment: I think ``Object.keys(json.paths)`` should get you the desired results.

Comment: where can i use this syntax that to get my result? i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. I use block Evaluate with next code:

```
$keys(paths)
```